# How to index a document with a condition inside [Javascript+ElasticSearch]

Tags: javascript, indexing, elasticsearch

My program does his stuff and creates at the end a .csv with some data.
I want to index a document with these data so I also call a function with something inside like this:

```
client.index({
index: 'blog',
  type: 'post',
  id: 1,
  body: {
    title: 'JavaScript Everywhere!',
    content: 'It all started when...',
    date: '2013-12-17'
  }
}, function (err, resp) {
  // ...
});
```

Now, what if for example I wanna have an "if" condition inside "body", for example store the title only if it is "Phyton"? . 
Similar question: what if I want to make an iteration having a "for"?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have if conditions inside `body` because you are creating a dictionary. You can have a simple ternary operation like

```
body {
  title: (t == "Python") ? "Python" : "Not Python"
}
```

You can't have a for loop either.

If you need to use complex condition statements to setup your data structure than you need to do that first and then pass it into your `client.index` function.